# Turning a hard error on incorrect template instantiation in SFINAE context into a soft error

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, sfinae

Let's say we're given a template instantiation `Container<U, Args...>` (think `Container` being an `std::vector`) and a non-template type T, and we need to check if we can call `push_back` on an object of type `Container<T>`. Here's the code that uses the detector idiom:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>
#include <boost/iterator.hpp>
#include <boost/range.hpp>

template<typename, typename>
struct replace
{
    using type = struct Error;
};

template<template<typename...> class Container, typename U, typename T>
struct replace<Container<U>, T>
{
    using type = Container<T>;
};

template<typename Container, typename T>
using replace_t = typename replace<Container, T>::type;

template<typename Placeholder, template<typename...> class Op, typename... Args>
struct isDetected : std::false_type {};

template<template<typename...> class Op, typename... Args>
struct isDetected<std::void_t<Op<Args...>>, Op, Args...> : std::true_type {};

template<typename Container, typename T>
using pushBackDetector = decltype(std::declval<Container&>().push_back(std::declval<T>()));

template<typename Container, typename T>
bool canPushBack()
{
    return isDetected<void, pushBackDetector, Container, T> {};
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << canPushBack<replace_t<std::vector<int>, double>, double>() << std::endl;
    std::cout << canPushBack<replace_t<std::set<int>, double>, double>() << std::endl;
    std::cout << canPushBack<replace_t<boost::iterator_range<std::string::iterator>, std::string::iterator>, double>() << std::endl;

    //std::cout << canPushBack<replace_t<boost::iterator_range<std::string::iterator>, int>, double>() << std::endl;
}
```

A live example is [available](https://wandbox.org/permlink/m3QIYtFFeYWBqYLO) at Wandbox.

Indeed, it correctly deduces that we can call `push_back` on `std::vector<double>`, but we can't do that on `std::set<double>` or on `boost::iterator_range<std::string::iterator>`.

Now let's check if we can call `push_back` on `boost::iterator_range<int>` and uncomment the last line! And now the code explodes so beautifully that I won't give the full error message here (better to do that on the live example linked above), but the gist of it is the compiler trying to instantiate `boost::iterator_range<int>` and turning the failure to instantiate some base type of that one into a hard error:

```
/opt/wandbox/boost-1.65.1/clang-5.0.0/include/boost/iterator/iterator_categories.hpp:119:60: error: no type named 'iterator_category' in 'std::__1::iterator_traits<int>'
        typename boost::detail::iterator_traits<Iterator>::iterator_category
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/wandbox/boost-1.65.1/clang-5.0.0/include/boost/range/iterator_range_core.hpp:156:32: note: in instantiation of template class 'boost::iterators::iterator_traversal<int>' requested here
        BOOST_DEDUCED_TYPENAME iterator_traversal<IteratorT>::type
                               ^
/opt/wandbox/boost-1.65.1/clang-5.0.0/include/boost/range/iterator_range_core.hpp:436:67: note: in instantiation of template class 'boost::iterator_range_detail::pure_iterator_traversal<int>' requested here
                    BOOST_DEDUCED_TYPENAME iterator_range_detail::pure_iterator_traversal<IteratorT>::type
                                                                  ^
prog.cc:31:61: note: in instantiation of template class 'boost::iterator_range<int>' requested here
using pushBackDetector = decltype(std::declval<Container&>().push_back(std::declval<T>()));
                                                            ^
prog.cc:28:31: note: in instantiation of template type alias 'pushBackDetector' requested here
struct isDetected<std::void_t<Op<Args...>>, Op, Args...> : std::true_type {};
                              ^
prog.cc:36:12: note: during template argument deduction for class template partial specialization 'isDetected<std::void_t<Op<Args...> >, Op, Args...>' [with Op = pushBackDetector, Args = <boost::iterator_range<int>, double>]
    return isDetected<void, pushBackDetector, Container, T> {};
           ^
```

On one hand, this makes perfect sense — indeed, `int` is not an iterator. On the other hand, it's very desirable to catch this incorrect instantiation and just return `false` from `canPushBack()` in this case. So, this is the question: is it possible to turn this hard error into a soft error and handle it gracefully?

Comment: "hard error" "soft error" what is that?

Comment: Error happens in `boost::iterator_range<int>`, not in `canPushBack`.

Comment: @jarod42, the OP knows; I think he wants the detection of push_back() validity to fail whenever Container<T> is not 'valid'. I don't think this is possible without some help from Container ...  because I think std::declval<Container<T>&>().push_back always requires Container<T> to implicit instantiate ...

Comment: I think the problem is in replace/replace_t - not to instantiate Container<T> if not valid type (provide struct Errror instead). But do not know if possible to achieve...

Comment: It doesn't look like `boost::iterator_range` is SFINAE friendly; we cannot make a `is_constructible` trait that works reliably for it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you cannot take a template that doesn't support SFINAE-detection and make it SFINAE-friendly without manual work specific to the type in question, and sometimes that isn't enough.

The best you can do is write a manual trait that does it for you, and an alias that SFINAE checks if it can be applied, and only returns a type if it can be.

What more, it isn't possible to detect if something is an iterator.  There are no standard-mandated SFINAE-friendly "is X an iterator" tests.  As a general rule, all iterators must support `std::iterator_traits<T>`, but there are *zero* requirements that non-iterators must generate a SFINAE friendly result when you pass them to `std::iterator_traits`, and in my experience passing `void*` to `std::iterator_traits` generates a non-SFINAE friendly result.

You could try to hack one -- detect the various things that an iterator must do (be dereferenceable, incrementable, equally compariable), but even there a type may not have SFINAE-friendly errors when you try it.  For example, take non-equally compariable type and put it in a `std::vector`, and attempting to do `==` can fail to compile with a hard error (at least the last time I checked).

A simple case is:

```
template<class T>
struct problem {
  static_assert(!std::is_same<T,int>{}, "oh oh");
};
```

passing `int` to `problem` cannot be SFINAE detected as being a problem.  If you instantiate `problem<int>`, you get a hard error.

Comment: Right, so this means my worst fear is true: I'll have to have a kludge checking if it's a `boost::iterator_range` (or perhaps something similar in the future shall the need arise) in my particular case. Thanks!

Comment: @0xd34df00d require the person passing the template *in* to provide a SFINAE friendly version if they want it to work in a SFINAE friendly manner.  For example, `template<class T> using my_iterator_range = apply_if< my_is_iterator<T>{}, boost::iterator_range, T >;`  `my_iterator_range` now becomes a SFINAE-friendly versoin of `boost::iterator_range`.  Not a kludge, but an input requirement to your metaprogramming code.